# Using R and IBrokers, what is the function to call to get the bid and ask prices of given stock symbol?

Tags: r, tws, ibrokers

I have not much else to add other than the title.
I simply need the name of the function.

Comment: See @brian's answer below, and also this tutorial might be useful to get you to that stage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdQ_svOV7kc

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the documentation? Check pg 18.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IBrokers/IBrokers.pdf

```
tws <- twsConnect()
contract <- twsEquity("QQQQ","SMART","ISLAND")
reqMktData(tws, contract)
```

Look at pg 8 to see how to handle incoming data.